# Function($param) add to function __construct

Tags: php

I have two functions in a class:

```
        public function __construct()
        {
          $this->page=$this->Pagination_page();
        }

        function Pagination_page($page){     
          return $page;
        }
```

This version is not working. How can I add to the `$this->page the Pagination_Page` value?

Comment: I think its not working,beacuse in other function I tried to call the $this->page but its '0'.

Comment: you don't send a value to the Pagination_page function, which means the function will return null, so either change the function so that it create a value or send a value with the call to Pagination_page

Answer (score 1):

To use a class in the manner you want it to, you will need to use getters and setters. Take a look at the following example:

```
class Pagination
{

    private $page;

    public function __construct($page = false)
    {
        if (false !== $page) {
            $this->page = $page;
        }
    }

    public function setPage($page)
    {
        $this->page = $page;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPage()
    {
        return $this->page;
    }
}

$pagination = new Pagination('1');
$pagination->setPage('3');
print_r($pagination->getPage()); // returns 3
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not working because the constructor is initialized when you instanciate the object - it's 0 there. But you cannot assign this value of $page at the start you  must call the method first. If you want to do this you should create it in the construct directly:

```
public function __construct($_page)
    {
      $this->page=$_page;
    }
```

If you want to use the "thing" you created then:

```
public function __construct($_page)
    {
      $this->page=$this->Pagination_page($_page);
    }
       function Pagination_page($page){     
           return $page;
    }
```